# I don't have enough Flint to light up all the braziers

Tags: battle-chasers-nightwar

For the quest in Balefire Cavern, Flint (consumable quest item) is required to light up the braziers. But I'm missing 2 more pieces. Where can I get more Flint? I fought some mobs outside and they didn't seem to drop any so far.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there's enough extra Flint in the Path of Fangs dungeon just to the right, over the mountains. Incidentally that's where the next story mission leads you.